# What is the suitable ML algorithm for predicting root cause of an ITSM ticket?

Tags: machine-learning

I have 11 months data from a ticketing tool which has columns like `Incident Number, Description, Status, Resolution Notes, Priority, Root Cause`. Example of Root Cause: `Access Request, Database Issue, Server Down, etc`. Most of the incidents are recurring and every month few new incidents will be recorded. Task is to predict the root cause for end of the month report based on the ticket description(only one independent variable). Kindly let me know which algorithm will best suit for this use-case.

Comment: This sounds like a text classification problem, are you familiar with those? Also: Other variables of interest might still be in the system. I'm thinking of things like date and time of submission, or the id of the author.

Comment: We intend to use only Description column for predicting the root cause. As you mentioned it falls into text classification, can I use scikit-learn and NLTK? Any particular supervised algorithms do you suggest?

Comment: There are multiple implementation options. I'm tempted to shout: Simple tokenization & Naive Bayes, as a starting point that is easy to understand. Later to be tweaked with things as LDA and SVM. Do you have a little info on the typical lenght of description, the frequency of the classes and the size of the vocabulary?